# NetSuite Eclipse Upload of scripts

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin, netsuite, suitecloud

i got this problem when i try to upload the SuiteScript file to the netsuite account , does anyone now the solution to this error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Tzu.png)

I tried to upload the suitescrpt file to the editor to execute the file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.